# Take an input value and see if it equals the defined object

Tags: javascript, dom

HTML:

```
<html>
<body>
<input type = "text" name = "name" id = "name"> </input>
<button type = "submit" id = "submit">Find Student </button>
<script type = "text/javascript" src="ObjectTest.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Javascript:

```
var Matt = {
  GPA: 4.0,
  Faculty: "Science",
  Year: 1
};
```

I have an object that I've defined with some values.

**What I am trying to do is to allow text to be entered into the textbox.
When the submit button is hit, a javascript function will be run that grabs the value in the textbox and if it equals the object value, then it will console.log the properties.**

Here is my better attempt:

```
function findStudent(){
 var student = document.getElementById('name').value;
 return student;
}
console.log(student);
```

Comment: Not much point in a submit button outside a form.

Answer (score 0):

Hard to know exactly what you're trying to achieve or where your object is coming from but your object probably needs to look something like:

```
   var student = {
    name:'Matt',
    gpa:4.0,
    faculty:'Science',
    year: 1
   }
```

Try something like:

```
function checkName(){
   var name = document.getElementById('name').val();
   if(name === student.name){
       console.log('same');
   }
   else{
       console.log('different');
   }
}
```

Called in your button, with something like:

```
<button onclick="checkName()">Check Student</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to think about the **structure**. There should be a lot of students. It's not practical to set multiple objects for each student:

```
var st1 = { ... }
var st2 = { ... }
```

Instead it's more practical to declare **one object** with **all** students. And put the values in an array:

```
var students = {
    "Matt": ["4.0", "science", "1.0"],
    "Laura": ["3.0", "comedy", "2.2"],
    ...
}
```

You can output the array as an info to the corresponding student:

```
function findStudent() {
    var info = [];
    var student = document.getElementById("name").value;
    for (name in students) {
        if (name === student) {
            info = students[name];
        }
    }
    alert(info);
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cph4u1nz/2/)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a submit button, it should be in a form. This also makes dealing with inputs easier, even if you don't want to submit the form. I've modified the object so that it has a *name* property.

```js
var Matt = {
  name: 'Matt',
  GPA: 4.0,
  Faculty: "Science",
  Year: 1
};

function checkValue(form) {
  if (form.studentName.value == Matt.name) {
    form.output.value = ('Match');
  } else {
    form.output.value = ('Not a match');
  }
  return false;
}
```

```html
<form onsubmit="return checkValue(this);">
  <label for="studentName">Name: <input name="studentName" id="studentName"></label>
  <button>Check the name</button>
  <br>
  <label for="output">Output: <input name="output" id="output"></label>
</form>
```

The body of the *checkValue* function could be:

```
form.output.value = form.studentName.value == Matt.name? 'Match' : 'Not a match';
```

However the longer version is simpler to understand.